# How to resolve "container failed to start error" while deploying a docker image to cloud run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

Problem statement: I have created a docker application ( a simple python code) and trying to deploy and automate run using Google Cloudrun but each time during deployment I see the below error :

command:

```
gcloud run deploy my_service_name --image gcr.io/project-id/image_name
```

Error

```
 Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more info
rmation.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  X Creating Revision... Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more inform
  ation.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  . Routing traffic...                                                                                                                                                                                     
Deployment failed
```

My Dockerfile

```
#FROM python:3.8
FROM python:latest
# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
COPY requirements.txt ./
# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copy main 
COPY main.py ./
ENV PORT = 8080
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

There is nothing fancy in my python program just running a bunch of sql queries and updating the BQ table.

I have used the [troubleshooting steps](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) listed by Google and the container runs on my local without any issue.

Can someone please guide me as to where am I going wrong ?

**Edit:** Updated the Dockerfile to ENV PORT=8080 (removed the space). Still receiving the same error . deployment Logs below

```
Deployment failed                                                                                                                                                                                          
DEBUG: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/run/deploy.py", line 258, in Run
    build_log_url=build_log_url)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/run/serverless_operations.py", line 1087, in ReleaseService
    self.WaitForCondition(poller)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/run/serverless_operations.py", line 594, in WaitForCondition
    return waiter.PollUntilDone(poller, None, wait_ceiling_ms=1000)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 326, in PollUntilDone
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 219, in RetryOnResult
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/run/serverless_operations.py", line 251, in Poll
    self._PollTerminalSubconditions(conditions, conditions_message)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/run/serverless_operations.py", line 230, in _PollTerminalSubconditions
    self._PossiblyFailStage(condition, message)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/run/serverless_operations.py", line 349, in _PossiblyFailStage
    message)
  File "/Users/analyst045/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/console/progress_tracker.py", line 915, in FailStage
    raise failure_exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
DeploymentFailedError: Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Logs below:

```
{
 insertId: "5ec6519000ca44b34efd"  
 labels: {
  instanceId: "00bf4bf02dd520b9906e825b7333299aac62e9e4f12e4090ccd3b3bfd2435203c13fbe3c09193bd6dd408286adf939dff830"   
 }
 logName: "projects/project-name/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-18T10:46:09.076605834Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   configuration_name: "measurement-protocol-hit"    
   location: "us-central1"    
   project_id: "project-id"    
   revision_name: "measurement-protocol-hit-00001-det"    
   service_name: "measurement-protocol-hit"    
  }
  type: "cloud_run_revision"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 textPayload: "Container called exit(0)."  
 timestamp: "2020-05-18T10:36:09.068639979Z"  
}
```

Comment: Is it fully managed Cloud Run? I've been able to deploy right now using your same Dockerfile. The only change I made was `ENV PORT=8080` (without blankspaces) and it worked out. If this is still failing, try using `gcloud run deploy my_service_name --image gcr.io/project-id/image_name --verbosity=debug` to have more information about the error and share it so we can help you further.

Comment: @bhito : tried as suggested - still same error. Have attached the logs above in the edit if it helps. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: And yes it's fully managed Cloud Run.

Comment: Go to the logs (stackdriver logging) you will have much more detail. Here you simply have the default error message. and I'm quite sure that there is no relation with the port!

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this:

```
ENV PORT = 8080
```

Not only as @supersam654 said it is the wrong syntax, `PORT` environment variable will be passed to your application by Cloud Run ––you don't pass it yourself like this.

As the has error said multiple times (what you posted is not "detailed logs"), you should:

> Logs for this revision might contain more information.

So go to https://console.cloud.google.com/run and fetch logs for this application.

You should probably make sure you test your container locally before deploying. Instructions can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local

Comment: Thanks for the response .  Have attached the logs above but it doesn't help much.                                                                        
 1. If we see the Codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-hello-python3/#4  or other Google Tutorials, they all have mentioned the ENV PORT , also isn't it part of the container runtime contract  as mentioned in the troubleshooting guide ?  2. As mentioned above the container is running on the local without any issues.  3. I'm just wondering is it must to deploy the code as a python app ?

Comment: what do you mean "you don't pass it yourself like this".  Are you saying you don't set the PORT in your Dockerfile?  where are you talking about?'

Comment: Don't set PORT anywhere yourself. It's given to you by Cloud Run in the runtime when it's deployed @PositiveGuy.

Comment: I set PORT and it's fine for me.  PORT specifies what port you want to expose from your container to Cloud Run I thought.

Comment: Neither PORT directive nor ENV PORT directive in dockerfile inform Cloud Run about anything. Read https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#port

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#), you can specify a port in one of two ways:

```
ENV <key> <value>
ENV <key>=<value> ...
```

Because you have spaces around `=`, Docker thinks you're using the first form where your key is `PORT` and your value is `= 8000` (which is not a number and probably why Cloud Run isn't working).

To fix it, either specify the port without spaces (`ENV PORT=8000`) or without an equals sign (`ENV PORT 8000`).

Comment: tried both . also tried changing the port to 800 (just for the sake) - still same error. (detailed logs above.). Thanks again